# Java Applet on Ubuntu Web Server

Tags: java, applet, sockets, signature

I have an java applet to sign documents digitally: http://www.pki.sanluis.gov.ar/PkiAsp/Paginas/Pagina.asp?PaginaId=54
I have a middleware to do this from a smart card.

I can't export the private key from the smart card, but I need to sign documents on cloud.

Have you any idea how can I do that?

I'm wondering if I can run the applet on server.

Thank you!!